# Strikethrough Element Without Going Over or Under Element

Tags: html, css

I want to draw lines to the left and right of an element up to the edge of their parent element.

I'm not sure how I could describe this otherwise, but maybe a screenshot will do the trick:

[image]

As you can see, this is close to perfect, and if I put

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the heading, then its even better, but then I can't see my nice rounded corners (red circled parts in screenshot) because it's then cut-off.

At the moment, as is, this is my HTML:

```
<div id="IntroPage" class="introPage">
    <div class="test">Heading</div>
</div>
```

Where "introPage" is the gray part you see.

My CSS for this:

```
.introPage {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

.test {
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-align: center;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    background: #0099FF;
    height: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.test:before {
    right: 10px;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

.test:after {
    left: 10px;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

Anyone has a better solution to this?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I've been looking at this for a while...I'm wondering if the best solution is to just add two divs...I can't seem to make anything work.

Comment: The only problem with that, is that the text we see in the center should then have a fixed width. but that can be a problem when I have different widths (eg: longer text). My attempt is to be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, but uses JS, will be to have 3 divs inside a parent div. the 1st and 3rd ones is the lines, and the 2nd one is the text. then I float 1 and 3 to the left and right, and use JS to do a calculation on the 2nd's width. once I have the width, I can then use CSS: calc(50% - [width of 2nd div]), by injecting the CSS with the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/nmtkre6e/2/)
Sorry , I had to use 2 divs for the blue lines so they would cooperate with the hybrid layout: flexbox for modern browsers and display table for a fallback.

## HTML

```
<div id="IntroPage" class="introPage flexBox">
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class="test">
        Heading
    </div>
    <div class='line'></div> 
</div>
```

## CSS

```
    body {
    background: grey;
}
.introPage {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 3em;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    display: table-row;
}
.test {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 1.5em;
    display: table-cell;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 20%;
}
.line {
    position: relative;
    background: #0099FF;
    height: .4em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 6px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 39%;
}

.flexBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanx! This is nice. I eventually ended up using jQuery to do the calculations for me in order to have a constant line start from the middle text. I did not want to use jQuery for this, but somethimes, it has to be.

Comment: Your'e most welcome, sir. If you have a jQuery solution, could you please post it? I'm not totally comfortable using jQuery for layout purposes and I'd like to see how you did it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    h2 { width:100%; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; line-height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 20px; } 
    h2 span { background:#fff; padding:0 10px; }
</style>

<h2><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></h2>
```

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zDGkw

Comment: Nice, I didn't know JQuery had a function for this... I was about to rewrite it in javascript.

Comment: Hmmm this looks promising. But i'd prefer a no-js solution. But i ll try this out in a few :)

Comment: Oh... no... same problem here as in my question... the moment the article's "overflow: hidden" is removed, they go over. That's my problem... it would have been OK if I did not want rounded corners on my 'strikethroughs'

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way would be to set the width of the test before and after elements to a smaller width (Say maybe 40% instead of 50%).

```css
.introPage {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

.test {
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-align: center;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    background: #0099FF;
    height: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.test:before {
    right: 10px;
}

.test:after {
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="IntroPage" class="introPage">
    <div class="test">Heading</div>
</div>
```

The best case solution would be to re-size the test before and after elements based on the width of the "test" class. I'm not so sure this is possible in css alone and you will likely have to use javascript to resize the width of those elements based on the size of the test element.

The basic outline of this process would be to calculate the width of the text, convert it from pixels to a percentage, then subtract that percentage from 100%, and divide by 2.

I may give this a shot later depending on how much time I have, if anyone wants to pick it up from here feel free to edit the post (community wiki style).

Comment: Yeah, still sits with the problem that if I have a longer heading... they still go over the edges evenually. In this case I can just hard code them all to specific pixels instead... but I want it to be dynamic as possible (responsive)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer...works with any page width.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGxNgB

```
<div id="IntroPage" class="introPage">
    <div class="test">Heading</div>
</div>

.introPage {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}

.test {
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  height:30px;

}

.test:before,
.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #0099FF;
    height: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  top:12px;
}

.test:before {
    float:right;
  right:-40px;
  pos

}

.test:after {
   float:left;
  left:-40px;

}
```

Comment: Hehe sorry, this is the other way around. the wrong parts in my screenshot is the circled pieces. They should not go "over" the gray area. I fixed that by doing a "overflow: hidden". but the problem there is that it cuts off, making it look edgy without the border-radius.

Comment: But the "blue" parts is correct in the way that they are over the gray... it just should not go over the gray edge.